# PHP arrow / method call operator ("->") precedence

Tags: php, operator-precedence

I'd like to have a reference stating clearly where PHP's arrow / method call operator (`->`) falls as regards the order of operator binding.

Unfortunately, the [authoritative PHP manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) on operator precedence doesn't list it.

Example where someone could have doubts whether this could throw an exception because `$price` was first cast to `string` and only then the method call `->times()` attempted:

```
return (string) $price->times($quantity);
```

In the answer, please indicate if there was any change here between PHP versions.

Bonus: does the static call (`::`) operator has the same precedence as `->`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$foo->bar(...)` is classified in [PHP's grammar](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/19-grammar.md#grammar-member-call-expression) as a **member-call-expression**.

This is a form of **callable-variable**, which itself is a form of **variable**. Essentially, a call to a member function on an object has the same precedence as any other "raw" variable - `$foo->bar(...)` and just `$foo` should be treated identically by the compiler. Neither is an "operator", and so they don't fit in the same hierarchy as the ones listed in the manual page you linked.

For your bonus question, `::` is classed as a **scoped-call-expression**, which holds the same "precedence".